# Serial Communication Eats incoming ASCII DC1 characters

Tags: binary, embedded, serial-port

I am implementing a serial interface to communicate with an external piece of hardware using /dev/ttyS0.  I have configured for RAW input and output as the data stream is in a packet format and encapsulated with Start of Message, Length Bytes and Binary Data.  Any DC1 or DC3 characters, 0x11 or 0x13, in the incoming data stream is eaten by the Linux OS (Latest Ubuntu).

I have a Windows PC and Realterm monitoring the communication and see the 0x11 and 0x13 characters on the monitor.  As far as I can tell, there are no other missing characters.

Here is my serial setup code (Note IXON, IXOFF, IXANY are disabled):

```
void Ser_Open_Port( unsigned char *port )
{
   tcgetattr(ser_handle, &ser_old_settings);
   tcgetattr(ser_handle, &ser_new_settings);

   // Set Baud Rate
   cfsetospeed(&ser_new_settings, baud); 

   // ~BRKINT - No Flush on Break
   // ~PARMRK, ~IGNPAR - Parity Error result in \0 char
   // ~ISTRIP - No 8th bit Strip
   // ~INLCR - No NL to CR Translate
   // ~IGNCR No Ignore CR
   // ~ICRNL No CR to NL Translate
   // ~IXON - No Software Flow Control on Output
   // ~IXOFF - No Software Flow Control on Output
   // ~IXANY - No Software Flow Control on Output
   // ~INPCK - Ignore Parity Checking
   ser_new_settings.c_iflag &= ~(BRKINT|PARMRK|IGNPAR|ISTRIP|INLCR|IGNCR|ICRNL|IXON|IXOFF|IXANY|INPCK);
   // IGNBRK - Ignore Break
   ser_new_settings.c_iflag |= (IGNBRK); 

   // ~OPOST - Implementation Defined Output Processing Off - Raw Output
   // All Other c_oflag bits are ignored
   ser_new_settings.c_oflag &= ~(OPOST);

   // ~ICANON - Not Canonical Input Mode
   // ~ECHO - No Echo
   // ~ECHOE - No Echo Erase
   // ~ECHONL - No Echo NL
   // ~ISIG - No Signals
   // ~IEXTEN - Implementation Defined Input Processing Off - Raw Input
   ser_new_settings.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON|ECHO|ECHOE|ECHONL|ISIG|IEXTEN);

   // ~PARENB - No Parity
   // ~CSTOPB - 1 stop bit 
   // ~CSIZE - Clear Character Size Bits
   ser_new_settings.c_cflag &= ~(PARENB|CSTOPB|CSIZE);
   // CS8 - Character Size 8 bits
   // CLOCAL -  Ignore Modem Control Lines
   ser_new_settings.c_cflag |= (CS8|CLOCAL); 

   // apply the settings
   tcsetattr(ser_handle, TCSANOW, &ser_new_settings);
   tcflush(ser_handle, TCOFLUSH);

   // Open Serial Port for Read/Write, and Non Blocking
   ser_handle = open(port, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY | O_NONBLOCK);
}
```

Here is where I read from the Serial Port Buffer:

```
   ser_charin_count = read( ser_handle, ser_charin, 30);
   if( ser_charin_count > 0 && ser_charin_count != 0xFFFFFFFF)
   {
   // Code to Process Message Bytes Here
   }
```

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Rather than edit the question you should post this as an answer yourself so it's useful for anyone else that comes along, and doesn't look like an unanswered question.

Comment: How do I change it to an answer?

Comment: you just scroll down to the bottom and you should see a box to type the answer and press 'post your answer'. Then just go back and edit the question to remove that part. Just to clarify don't move the whole lot - just last paragraph and probably drop the doh etc.

Comment: @PeterJ - Thanks for helping a Forum Noob.

Answer (score 2):

The error was in not opening the port first to get the ser_handle initialized to the correct port attr structure. I put the open at the top of the subroutine and then used the tcgetattr and tcsetattr functions to correctly modify the port values.